# TO dynamically change the href of anchor tag according to calling anchor tag..Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript

Conisder anchor tags a1,a2,a3 in div1 and if a person clicks on a1 thn a div2 sud open and it contains some anchor tags with some default href value...how to change the href values for those anchor tags in div2 according to the anchors selected in div1.....

Example...

One


  

  
   1One
   1Two

  

  
   2One

in the above coding...we need to change the href of a3,a4,a9,a10,etc...according to the calling anchor....if calling anchor is a1...thn a3 href sud be help.html...etc...like tht...please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Ok...

```
links = new Array(
  '#link-1' : 'a_page.html',
  '#link-2' : 'another_page.html',
  '#link-3' : 'yet_another_page.html'
);

$(function () {
  $('#div1 a[href^=#link-]').click(function () {
    $('#div2').show();
    $('#div2 #a3').href(links[$(this).href()]);
  });
});
```

What this does is set an associative array containing the pages which correspond to the hrefs of elements in the first div. Then when one of the of the links is clicked (matched by whether its starts with `#link-` the second div is revealed, and the link with id `a3` is changed to match the page specified in the array.

**Edit:**
Include this in the `<head>` part of your site:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then below it include the above script in `<script></script>` tags. The divs need to have the id="div1" and id="div2" attributes respectively, and the link to be changed needs id="a3" for this to work.

Comment: i really thank you Nathan...but can u please explain clearly...that where to add the function in my code? in onclick event waht sud be given?

Comment: see my edit. That should explain it. If you need more help, just ask.